# Rust: struct method that spawn a thread and calls another instance method

Tags: multithreading, rust

This is a follow up of [Rust: Struct that performs an action indefinitely with ability to start and stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74109168/rust-struct-that-performs-an-action-indefinitely-with-ability-to-start-and-stop?noredirect=1#comment130847186_74109168)

Basically, I am trying to write a struct which holds a `state` enum, and runs some behaviour; but only if this enum is `State::Running`.

This is the footprint:

```rust
enum Status {
  Stopped,
  Running,
}

pub trait IMachine {
  fn new() -> Self;
  fn start(&mut self);
  fn stop(&mut self);
  fn run(&self);
}

pub struct Machine {
  status: Status,
}
```

So it can be consumed this way:

```rust
mod services;
use services::Machine;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
  let mut machine = Machine::new();
  machine.start();
  thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
  machine.stop();

  println!("Finished");
}
```

Now on `machine.start()` method I need to spawn a thread that calls `self.run()`. But I'm having lifetime issues —`error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of associated function`—.
This is my implementation:

```rust
impl IMachine for Machine {
  fn new() -> Self {
    Machine {
      status: Status::Stopped,
    }
  }

  fn start(&mut self) {
    println!("Starting");
    self.status = Status::Running;

    let my_thread = thread::spawn(move || { // <-- Lifetime related errors
      self.run();
    });
    let _join = my_thread.join();
  }

  fn stop(&mut self) {
    println!("Starting");
    self.status = Status::Stopped;
  }

  fn run(&self) {
    let now = SystemTime::now();
    if self.status == Status::Running {
      loop {
        println!("{:#?}", self.status,);
        println!(
          "Elapsed since last start: {}\n",
          now.elapsed().unwrap().as_millis()
        );

        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The full error is:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
  --> src/main.rs:35:21
   |
31 |     fn start(&mut self) {
   |              ---------
   |              |
   |              `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
   |              let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
35 |       let my_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
   |  _____________________^
36 | |       self.run();
37 | |     });
   | |      ^
   | |      |
   | |______`self` escapes the associated function body here
   |        argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0521`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I checked other questions, as [How to use self while spawning a thread from method](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-use-self-while-spawning-a-thread-from-method/8282/5); but their solution is to clone the instance of `self`, loosing its state —which is used by `machine.run()`—.

I've been trying to find the proper lifetime for a while, but I'm starting to think this is not the correct approach.

Here is [the code failing in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9cc3c2fb9c27dea113c1f3032315ffba). Any help will be welcome.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html

Comment: @ÖmerErden yes, I'm trying with Mutex, will edit with an update.

Comment: Using an `Arc` is the proper solution here, I don't understand what is your problem with that.

Comment: Generally, rather than shared state, it would be better to use channels to communicate.